# Get rid of "nameless" node in mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial

I found a nameless node in my mercurial repository.

On executing the tag listing command "hg tags" as part of the generated output, I find the same node mentioned twice.

The output of hg tags command contains the following duplicate nodes:

```
xyz_release_tag                    daa262c10
                                   daa262c10
```

In one of the entries, the node has a name but the other entry the node does not have a name.

I am in the process of migrating the mercurial repository to git and I am using fast-export to do the conversion. 
The presence of this "nameless" node causes errors during the conversion process. Similar issue has been discussed at: https://github.com/frej/fast-export/issues/1.

As a quick workaround, I made a quick change to my local repository cache file. There is a file by name "tags2-visible" that gets created after I run the hg tags command for listing. Once I modify this file to remove the entry for the nameless node, it disappears and the conversion process succeeds.

I am not very sure if this is the right way to do it or if at all there is any other way.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Can you clarify and give an example of what you understand to see when you talk of a "nameless node" in the context of tagged nodes?

Comment: @planetmaker I have updated my question with an excerpt of the command output.

Comment: Maybe that node has several tags, one being a badly-cbhosen (nearly) invisible tag. Check all tags attached to that node by means of hg log -rdaa262c10 (no clue how you could have chose that, hg won't let me choose an empty tag; maybe some other tools let you do that)

Answer (score 2):

Resulting quickfix:

```
hg tags # Creates .hg/cache/tags2-visible
# Fix the nameless tag
sed -rie 's/^([^ ]+) $/\1 \1/' .hg/cache/tags2-visible
```

How I came to the solution:

```
$ hg tags | tail -3
PRODUCION_18032010               216:3e0a6415bbde
                                 166:809065c08005
PRODUCION                        125:d98f65c06bac
$ # Where is the problem?
$ grep -r 809065c08005
.hg/cache/tags2-visible:809065c08005ef2d261f10f72f17ea5fcd1e7540
$ # Add " test" to the end of this line
$ sed -i .hg/cache/tags2-visible -e 's/809065c08005ef2d261f10f72f17ea5fcd1e7540/809065c08005ef2d261f10f72f17ea5fcd1e7540 test/'
$ # Checking the edition
$ grep -r 809065c08005
.hg/cache/tags2-visible:809065c08005ef2d261f10f72f17ea5fcd1e7540 test
$ # Checking the validity of the hack
$ hg tags | tail -3
PRODUCION_18032010               216:3e0a6415bbde
test                             166:809065c08005
PRODUCION                        125:d98f65c06bac
```

After editing .hg/cache/tags2-visible adding a label to the branch fast-export worked for me.

Anyone see any problem in editing .hg/cache/tags2-visible in this way?